# How to read the new windowsupdate.log on Windows 2016?

Tags: etw, windows-update

I used to read windowsupdate.log file to troubleshoot issues on Windows Update process. In that file I could check when cab file was not signed or WUA was not running or not properly installed or if the system was using the Windows Update process or a third party tool. But starting with Windows 2016 the windowsupdate.log file was replaced by ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) as commented in this link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518345
The link also explains how to use a PowerShell script to convert ETW file in readable files. But the point is that even these "readable files" I cannot find how to extract the same information I got in the old windowsupdate.log file. The resulting file only provides a list of GUID files that I suppose the installed files.

Comment: which issues do you have to install update?

Comment: I think this question is a better fit on Server Fault, as this is not related to programming, but, rather related to infrastructure administration.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful this was already [answered on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/899032/197546)

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I created this question because I had already found the answer you are pointing in Microsoft help doc, which does not help. The point is how to interpret the log file content generated after use the script suggested by Microsoft.